# example of linked list storing and retrieving through NSUserDefault class

Tags: iphone

I have 1 Linked list object and i want to use that object as for storing and retrieving through
any class for state maintenance in objective-c.
Is there any example for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State maintenance? For any class in objective-c? Why not use [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

There's a limit on what kinds of objects you're allowed to use (e.g. NSSets are not allowed but NSArrays are), but you can then store that dictionary straight off into [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to preserve state across runs.

E.g.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    NSUserDefaults *savedData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    self.settingsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
        [savedData dictionaryForKey:@"settings"]];
    // ...
}
```

to grab, then

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *savedData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savedData setObject:self.settingsDict forKey:@"settings"];
    [savedData synchronize];
    // ...
}
```

to save.